# How do you set up Bundles and Get the data back

Tags: java, android, sdk

I would like to know how I would save my variables in bundles and then get the data back with the `onResume()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to override onSaveInstanceState:

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putString("key", "Hello World");
}
```

To restore data, override onRestoreInstanceState (your onCreate will also receive this Bundle):

```
@Override
public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    String myString = savedInstanceState.getString("key");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the docs for [onSaveInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29) and [onRestoreInstanceState()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29). these are lifecycle methods on your activity class.